# How to install Tizen TV profile on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: linux

I also asked this on the actual Tizen community forums, but just in case no one replies on my thread in the Tozen forums, I posted here.

I want to be able to have Tizen TV profile on my Raspberry Pi 4. In other words I want to have Tizen with the TV UI just as if I was on a samsung TV, except it's on my Raspberry Pi 4.

I know its possible because it was done with the Raspberry Pi 2, but they just haven't updated the guide. So I guess my real question is: Is there a modern way to do this like the method in [this guide](https://wiki.tizen.org/How_to_use_Mesa_with_GL/EGL_GPU_acceleration_and_DRM_for_Tizen_3.0_TV_profile_(wayland_backend)_on_RPI2) that tells you how to install Tizen TV profile on a raspberry Pi 4?

Comment: It looks like there's a 'native' Rpi 3 image https://download.tizen.org/releases/milestone/tizen/5.5-unified/tizen-5.5-unified_20200812.1/images/standard/ there. Might be worth a try? I don't have anything newer than a oldschool one so I can't really try it

Comment: Yeah, you're completely right. I was silly to make this question in the first place, but I just wasn't sure if the image that can be flashed to the RPi now can be configured like the TV like the old guide I linked. But, it is indeed the correct image. Now what do I do with this question...

Comment: I'd say that documenting what you did to get it working would be a useful answer. Turn my speculative guess into the documentation you needed. What did you use? what problems did you run into, etc